# How to use vivado's simulation tool to simulate Vivado's floating point IP core？

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to use the simulation tool of vivado to simulate Vivado's floating point IP core. My testbench is as follows:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_test();

// input
reg sys_clk;
reg sys_rst_n;

// output
wire    [63:0]  dataa;
wire    [63:0]  datab;
wire    [63:0]  result;
wire    res_valid;

initial begin
    sys_clk = 1'b0;
    sys_rst_n = 1'b0;
    # 200
    sys_rst_n = 1'b1;
end

always #10 sys_clk = ~sys_clk;

test u_test(
    .sys_clk (sys_clk),
    .sys_rst_n (sys_rst_n),
    
    .dataa  (dataa),
    .datab  (datab),
    
    .dataa_valid(),
    .datab_valid(),
    .res_valid(res_valid),
    
    .result  (result)
);


endmodule
```

and the model test is as follows:

```
//`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test(
    input           sys_clk,
    input           sys_rst_n,
    
    output reg [63:0]   dataa,
    output reg [63:0]   datab,
    
    output reg          dataa_valid,
    output reg          datab_valid,
    
    output  reg         res_valid,
    
    output  reg         result

    );

reg [9:0]  cnt;
wire [63:0] data_result;
wire        result_valid;

always @ (posedge sys_clk or negedge sys_rst_n)
begin 
    if(!sys_rst_n) 
        cnt <= 26'd0; 
     else if(cnt < 10'd1000)
        cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
     else 
        cnt <= 10'd0; 
end

always @(posedge sys_clk or negedge sys_rst_n)
begin
    if (!sys_rst_n)
        result <= 63'b0;
    else if(cnt == 10'd300)
        begin
            dataa <= 63'H3FF0000000000000;   // adder a
            datab <= 63'H3FF0000000000000;   // adder b
            res_valid <= 63'H000000000000000000;   // result
            dataa_valid <= 1'b1;
            datab_valid <= 1'b1;
        end
     else if(cnt == 10'd700)
        begin
            result <= data_result;
            res_valid <= result_valid;   //get result
        end
      else
            result <= result;    
end

add add (
  .aclk(sys_clk),                               // input wire aclk
  .s_axis_a_tvalid(dataa_valid),            // input wire s_axis_a_tvalid
  .s_axis_a_tdata(dataa),              // input wire [63 : 0] s_axis_a_tdata
  .s_axis_b_tvalid(datab_valid),            // input wire s_axis_b_tvalid
  .s_axis_b_tdata(datab),              // input wire [63 : 0] s_axis_b_tdata
  .m_axis_result_tvalid(result_valid),  // output wire m_axis_result_tvalid
  .m_axis_result_tdata(data_result)    // output wire [63 : 0] m_axis_result_tdata
);
endmodule
```

I want to simulate the `add` IP core of the floating point, but the result is wrong:
[image: simulate result]

The result of the calculation is ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my testbench?

Comment: 63:0 is 64 bits but your values are 63'h  i.e. `dataa <= 63'H3FF0000000000000;`

Answer (score 1):

My simulator gave me a compile warning about a width mismatch for the `result` signal.  You declared it as 64 bits in the testbench, but only 1 bit in the design.  Assuming you really want 64 bits, change:

```
output  reg         result
```

to:

```
output  reg [63:0]  result
```